# Can Google Places API pull specific types of places, like schools, without a location?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I want to have users able to search their school and Google Places API return a list of results (School Names along with addresses).

eg. User enters "Springfield Elementary" and the Places API gives the top results for that. Is that possible at all?

And also without knowing the user's location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have a look at the Places API [text search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search).

For example, the following request can search places that contain  "Springfield Elementary" and have a type "school":

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Springfield%20Elementary&type=school&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Visually, it looks like

[image]

I hope this helps!